# Edit Facebook share title and description

Tags: html, facebook, share, facebook-sharer

how do you edit the title and description of a specific link in your website when you share it on your facebook wall? For example I have a link in my website that opens a pdf file in a new tab, and I copied and paste the link in my facebook wall, but the title and description is showing the link. I know we use the `<meta property="og:title" content="title">` and all those other meta property, but how do we use it in a specific link in our website? for example like sharing a link in facebook that opens pdf file in my website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Like Button counts the likes of a PDF but does not actually post the activity?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13615310/like-button-counts-the-likes-of-a-pdf-but-does-not-actually-post-the-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go take a look here:

http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-for-your-iframe-tab/

Hope it will help!

Comment: I also found this website to be really useful too! http://www.webdesign.org/html-and-css/tutorials/how-to-create-a-share-button-for-your-site.22180.html